# SQL Where In not finding values I know exist

Tags: sql, powerschool

I work in a school district that uses Powerschool, and Powerschool has a custom report system that allows users to enter in SQL queries directly. When I use the custom report :

```
SELECT T.DCID, T.LastFirst, T.teachernumber, T.Users_DCID
FROM TEACHERS T 
WHERE T.STATUS=1 and T.SCHOOLID=~(curschoolid)
ORDER BY T.LAST_NAME ASC, T.FIRST_NAME ASC
```

I get a populated table like this:

```
DCID    lastfirst   teachernumber   users_dcid

5433    -------------   216335  5433
7855    -------------   216430  7855
7576    -------------   216376  7576
26021   -------------   7365739166  9748
```

But when I modify my query to add in selecting for certain data:

```
SELECT T.DCID, T.LastFirst, T.teachernumber, T.Users_DCID
FROM TEACHERS T 
WHERE T.teachernumber IN (216335, 216430, 7365739166) and T.STATUS=1 and T.SCHOOLID=~(curschoolid)
ORDER BY T.LAST_NAME ASC, T.FIRST_NAME ASC
```

The output is:

```
No data available in table
```

I've looked up the documentation and t.teachernumber is a string(20). So I tried adding CONVERT(string(20), 216335) to the WHERE IN () but that still came up with nothing.

What is wrong withy my query?

Comment: use `'216335'` single quotes around strings

Comment: One of the reasons I am modifying this is because I am modifying a plugin as well. The plugin takes a list of teacher numbers and creates a query to select them, and then modifies them in bulk. I need to get the query logic worked out in a report before I can modify the plugin.

Comment: sounds like an ambitious quest.   Good luck!

Comment: Hogan, that seems to have corrected my issue. I tried this with double quotes and it did not work, is sql always done with single quotes? 
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Yes SQL is always with single quotes, C and C like are double quotes and JavaScript is both.  Because JavaScript is the crazy step-child.

Answer (score 7):

You want this:

```
WHERE T.teachernumber IN ('216335', '216430', '7365739166') -- etc
```

String constants use single quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.DCID, T.LastFirst, T.teachernumber, T.Users_DCID FROM TEACHERS T 
       WHERE T.teachernumber IN ('216335', '216430', '7365739166') 
             AND T.STATUS=1 AND T.SCHOOLID=~(curschoolid)
ORDER BY T.LAST_NAME ASC, T.FIRST_NAME ASC
```